# php - how to get the value of an element and insert it to database?

Tags: php

I have links that have will open a new tab with a pdf file when it is clicked. I want the name of the clicked link to be inserted into the database but i don't get it. I have these line of codes:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn'])) {
    $email = $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM files");
    echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>
             <th>File Id</th>
             <th>File Name</th>
          </tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['fileId']."</td>";
                // echo "<td><a class='insert' name='file' href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['fileName']."</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a class='insert' name='".$row['fileName']."' href=''>".$row['fileName']."</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

i want the value of the <a> tag will be inserted in database. I hope you will help me.

Comment: You mean when you click the link or on this page?

Comment: My fault . I want the name of the file not the name of the link.

Comment: The name of the file is already in the DB, no? I'm not sure what your goal is but it sounds like you're headed down the wrong path.

Comment: yeah i think so. Thanks for the response. I will try another method for this one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Google I found on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) this result:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Being that you have not specified a table name nor schema it is difficult to help you further. An example would be `INSERT INTO clicked_urls (url) VALUES ($row['fileName'])`

Other factors you need to consider is how are you going to react to the user having clicked the link. Are you depending on PHP only? Are you using AJAX? The above will help you insert your data but you need to consider how you are going to handle the process.

Edit: Try something like this ... your `urlclick.php` will execute the SQL INSERT command discussed above.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$().ready(function() {
  $('.insert').click(function() {
    $.post('urlclick.php',{filename:this.filename});
  });
});
```

Comment: i'm wrong with the question. I want to get the name of the file from the link. Im sorry

Comment: You might want to look at AJAX to respond to an onclick event to post the attr('name') to a PHP script to insert that value using the example SQL instruction provided.

Comment: what does this line : $.post('urlclick.php',{filename:filename}); do ?

Comment: the filename:filename part

Comment: thanks Steven. I searched more on this and i found it very useful and solved my problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  The $.post() is an AJAX call to "POST" data to a URL, in this case 'urlclick.php'. Within the {} you find the resource name and value to POST.